# Scroll Issue in Android Automation using SeeTest + Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, seetest

I am using SeeTest + Selenium Webdriver + JAVA for Automating a Android application

There is one contact page there are 15 fields .  After filling 5th field the keyboard is overlapping the 6th fields so i need to scroll down for adding 6th fields and so on

But i am not able to scroll the page in automation so please help me regarding this SCROLL issue

Comment: May you want to show which par of your code is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   client.elementSwipeWhileNotFound("NATIVE", "id=nav_drawer", "Down", 0, 2000, "NATIVE", "text=History", 0, 1000, 5, true))
```

or normal scroll method available to use-

```
  client.scroll(500,500);
```

Comment: COuld you add some more information so that the original poster and anyone else with the same problem can understand when to use the scroll method vs swipe while not found; any extra initialization they might need and so on. That will make this a much better answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
   executor.swipeWhileNotFound(direction, offset, element);
```

Comment: Could you add some description around this code snippet? Your code might be exactly what the OP needs, but without context the original poster and others with the same problem may have trouble using your suggestion.